# I have a table of rows with checkboxes in columns. How do i select a particular checkbox

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML structure. A table with rows, the 2nd column has the text displayed e.g. Title (in row 1), FName (in row 2), SNAME (in row3), GENDER etc. 
The 3rd column has a checkbox for each row.
I am trying to select a particular checkbox.  E.g. my method will accept a parameter (the name of the text value in the row e.g. TITLE).
The method will select the checkbox for TITLE.
When i call the method again with parameter FNAME, the checkbox for FNAME will be clicked.
I am using Selenium Webdriver with Python

I have tried the following XPATH to identify the checkbox:

```
//span[@title="TITLE" and contains(text(), "TITLE")]/following-sibling::*

//span [text()="TITLE"]/../../preceding-sibling::td/div/input[@type="checkbox"]
```

These do not find the checkbox for the row called TITLE

I can get to the TITLE with the following XPATH.

```
//span [text()="TITLE"]
```

My code snippet is:

```
        def add_mapping2(self, name):
    try:
        checkbox = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span [text()="+name+"]/../../preceding-sibling::td/div/input[@type="checkbox"]') 
        checkbox.click()
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        return False
    return True
```

From my unittest.Testcase class I call the method as follows:

```
class MappingsPage_TestCase(BaseTestCase):

    def test_add_mappings(self):
        mappingsPage = projectNavigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Mappings")
        mappingsPage.add_mapping2("TITLE")
        mappingsPage.add_mapping2("SNAME")
```

The HTML is:

```
 <table id="data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr class="GOFU2OVFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <tr class="GOFU2OVEH GOFU2OVGH GOFU2OVPG GOFU2OVMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVFH GOFU2OVHG GOFU2OVHH GOFU2OVAH GOFU2OVNG">
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVFH GOFU2OVHH GOFU2OVAH GOFU2OVNG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-792" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span title="TITLE" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">TITLE</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVFH GOFU2OVHH GOFU2OVBH GOFU2OVOG GOFU2OVAH GOFU2OVNG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-793" style="outline-style:none;" tabindex="0">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="" tabindex="-1"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GOFU2OVFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVHG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-791" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="radio" name="rbCrossRow124"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-792" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="FNAME" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">FNAME</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVBH">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-793" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GOFU2OVEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
    <tr class="GOFU2OVFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="4">
    <tr class="GOFU2OVEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="5">
    <tr class="GOFU2OVFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="6">
    more rows with names with checkboxes etc......
</tbody>
</table>
```

What XPATH could I use to get the checkbox for TITLE, FNAME etc?
I have the table ID "data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body"
Maybe there is a way to start from the table ID and use a for loop to iterate through the rows and find the particular checkbox?

Thanks.

Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would use the following xpath expression

```
String xpath = "//span[@title = 'TITLE']/ancestor::tr[1]//input[@type = 'checkbox']"
```

What it does:

- first search for a span element with your parameter (pls change 'TITLE' to the variable you are using)
- then find the first ancestor element that is a tr-element
- from there find the input element that is your checkbox within this tr-element

You could then refine to sth like this:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body"));
WebElement checkbox = table.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the interest of others whom come across a similar problem.  My Python code which I have used for the above answer is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def add_mapping(self, name):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        try:
            checkbox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@title = "%s"]/ancestor::tr[1]//input[@type = "checkbox"]' % name)))
            #table_id = self.driver.find_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID, 'data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body')))
            #checkbox = table_id.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@title = "TITLE"]/ancestor::tr[1]//input[@type = "checkbox"]')
            checkbox.click()
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        return True
```

The table id i commented out also works.